# Heatmap.2 using multiple gradients and colours

Tags: r, colors, gradient, heatmap

I have a list of data I want to represent with heatmap.2. 
These are my parameters

- <-1 = solid colour
- 0-2 = gradient colour
- 2-5 = gradient colour
- 5-10 = gradient colour
- 10-20 = gradient colour
- 20+ = solid colour

The error it is giving me is below

> Error in image.default(1:nc, 1:nr, x, xlim = 0.5 + c(0, nc), ylim = 0.5 +  : 
>     must have one more break than colour

This is my code for col_breaks and cols

```
    col_breaks<-unique(c(-1,seq(0,2,by=20),seq(2.0001,5,by=20),seq(5.0001,10,by=20),
    seq(10.0001, 20,by=20),20.001))
    mycols<-c("blue",colorRampPalette(colors = c("green","yellow"))(length(col_breaks)),
    colorRampPalette(colors = c("orange","red"))(length(col_breaks)),
    colorRampPalette(colors = c("purple","pink"))(length(col_breaks)),
    colorRampPalette(colors = c("brown","black"))(length(col_breaks)),
    "purple")
```

This is what I write to get my heatmap but it is giving me that error.

```
    heatmap.2(mat_data,col=mycols,breaks=col_breaks)
```

Thank you.